# Django - sort QuerySet by backwards related model's field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following (simplified) models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Recommendation(models.Model):
    post=models.ForeignKey(Post)
    submit_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And I want to get the list of distinct `Posts` ordered by `Recommendation's` submit time.
The first way I tried was the straighforward:

```
Post.objects.order_by('recommendation__submit_time').distinct()
```

But surprisingly this gave a QuerySet with duplicate Post objects. [Turns out the rows are actually different because Django adds extra columns for the ordering, but does not return them in the results](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct).

Looking around I found a couple answers on SO, including to use aggregation instead of ordering:

```
Post.objects.all().annotate(Max('recommendation__submit_time')).order_by('recommendation__submit_time__max')
```

Or to de-normalize the model and add a `last_recommended_time` field to `Post`.

Most of the questions/answers already in SO are a couple years old, so I was wondering if there's a more idiomatic and straightforward way to do this than those suggested hacks.

EDIT:
Just thought I made it clear:
The solutions listed above do work and I'm using them (albeit not in production). I'm just interested in better solutions to this issue.

Comment: What about getting the distinct queryset first then ordering it? posts = Post.objects.all().distinct() and then posts.order_by('recommendation__submit_time')

Comment: I tried that too. Returns duplicates as well.

Comment: What about: Post.objects.order_by('recommendation__submit_time').distinct('title')

Comment: Clever, but doesn't work either.

Comment: Does it return posts with duplicate titles?

Comment: Yes, it basically returns the same as our other tries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about using [raw sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/sql/)

```
Post.objects.raw("""
    SELECT DISTINCT post FROM
        (SELECT appname_post.post_id AS post, appname_recommendation.submit_time
        FROM appname_post
        INNER JOIN appname_recommendation 
        ON appname_post.post_id = appname_recommendation.post_id
        ORDER_BY appname_recommendation.submit_time)
    """)
```